# class not being recognized as friend

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, friend, boost-smart-ptr

I have two classes say `foo` and `bar`. The constructor of `foo` is `private` so as to only allow the `bar` class to instantiate it.

```
// foo.h   
class foo
{
  friend class bar;
private:
  foo()
  {}
};

// bar.h
class bar
{
public:
  bar()
  {
    foo* f = new foo();
  } 
};
```

Also I am using `boost::shared_ptr` however for simplicity I did not mention it here

However when I attempt to build the program I get the error

> In instantiation of ‘typename boost::detail::sp_if_not_array::type
>   boost::make_shared() [with T = bar; typename
>   boost::detail::sp_if_not_array::type = boost::shared_ptr]’:|
>   /home/..../Projects/CodeBlocks/../bar.cpp|18|required from here|
>   /home/..../Projects/CodeBlocks/../foo.h|23|error: ‘foo::foo()’ is
>   private| ||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 2 warnings (0 minutes, 5
>   seconds) ===|

Is it because bar.h gets built first? If so, any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: `bar` might be `foo`'s friend, but `boost::make_shared` isn't. Use the `boost::shared_ptr` constructor directly instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am using `boost::shared_ptr` however for simplicity I did not mention it here

Ironically, that is the very thing that's making your code fail to compile. Without it, the example you've shown compiles without errors.

The problem is that you're trying to use `boost::make_shared` to create the `shared_ptr`. This will lead to `make_shared` attempting to construct a `foo`, which of course fails, because you've declared `bar` to be a `friend` of `foo`'s, but `make_shared` isn't a `friend`.

Use the `shared_ptr` constructor directly instead, and pass it a pointer to a `foo` object that has been allocated by `bar`.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc6d15fc1a13ac2f)

---

Note that declaring `boost::make_shared` as a `friend` is not a reliable solution either because it may delegate the actual construction to some other function.